# PHP SFTP Simple File Upload

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm using phpseclib - SFTP class and am trying to upload a file like so -

```
$sftp = new Net_SFTP('mydomain.com');
if (!$sftp->login('user', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}
$sftp->put('/some-dir/',$fileTempName);
```

The file however isn't being uploaded inside `some-dir` but is uploaded one directory before (to the starting directory, lets say it's root). This is driving me crazy, I think I've tried all combinations of `some-dir/` or `/some-dir` or `/some-dir/`, but the file won't upload there.

Comment: First Check the current working directory in SFTP. Use $sftp->pwd(). Then you will be able to provide the correct path for uploading files. Secondly, you have to provide the filepath. example,  $sftp->put('/some-dir/filename_remote','localfile');

Comment: $sftp->put('/some-dir/filename_remote','localfile',  NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE) will upload the files. Sorry for missing  NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE in my previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your put is doing what you think it is doing.  According to the docs, you need to do a `Net_SFTP::chdir('/some-dir/')` to switch to the directory you want to send file to, then `put($remote_file, $data)`, where `remote_file` is the name of file, and `$data` is the actual file data.

Example Code:

```
<?php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$sftp = new Net_SFTP('www.domain.tld');
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $sftp->pwd() . "\r\n";
$sftp->put('filename.ext', 'hello, world!');
print_r($sftp->nlist());
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I think that will do . So just to clarify (if anyone else has this problem) . $sftp->put first param is the file name to be created(uploaded) on the server , second param is the data (either a string text or a file handle) . If you want to upload to a specific directory use Net_SFTP::chdir('somedir') to change to that dir before you use put .