# Uploading a file via website to SFTP server

Tags: sftp, file-transfer

I'm building a website. I have the SFTP login credentials for the server.

I'm trying to make it so that a user can select a file on their hard-drive, and upload the file to a remote computer through SFTP.

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: My original title was "Transfer a file from website through sftp to another computer". This new title may be more technically correct, but those are not the words I used when searching for an answer to my question. Hopefully google will pick this up, so that other people who don't know what they're doing, like myself, are able to find it even if they don't know the precise language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I assume you use (or can use) PHP. You didn't specify, what technology you are using.*

Start with reading:

- [POST method uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) - for transferring a file from the client's machine to your website
- [PHP SFTP Simple File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13498910/850848) or [How do i use phpseclib to upload file from my php server -> someOther server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15518049/850848) - for transferring a file from your website to the SFTP

That combined together gets you a code like:

```php
include('Net/SFTP.php');

$uploaded_file = $_FILES["attachment"]["tmp_name"];

$sftp = new Net_SFTP("example.com");
if (!$sftp->login('username', 'password'))
{
    die("Connection failed");
}

$sftp->put(
    "/remote/path/".$_FILES["attachment"]["name"],
    file_get_contents($uploaded_file));
```

This is a very simplified code, lacking lots of validation and error checking.

The code uses the [phpseclib library](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score -1):

If you are in Windows, you can use a FTP Client like [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/)... If you are in Linux, use te [SCP](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) command:

> scp /home/me/myfile.dat user:password@remoteserver:/remotedir

Comment: I'm not trying to upload a file from my own computer one time. I'm building a website. This process needs to be automated to upload files from random people.

Comment: Ooopss, depends of the language you are using... You should try PHP and the [ssh2_sftp](http://php.net/manual/es/function.ssh2-sftp.php)

Check this [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9572314/uploading-files-with-sftp)